# behave: error: format=cucumber_json:PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter is unknown

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

I am trying to implement: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Behave+in+Python

It's generating a report in cucumber format for Xray test management tool.

But on running command:

```
behave --format=cucumber_json:PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter -o cucumber.json  --format=json -o behave.json
```

It's throwing me an error:

> behave: error: format=cucumber_json:PrettyCucumberJSONFormatter is unknown

Though according to the documentation of Xray I have placed my `cucumber_json.py` in my root directory.

My project directory:

```
behave_example
    - features
        - steps
        - try.py
    - cucumber_json.py
    - __init__.py
```

You can find cucumber_json.py here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Behave+in+Python

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to Python load the custom file in the actual folder, you should set this environment variable in the folder with code :

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please be more specific? Which folder with code are you referring to?

Comment: @MonicaVoinescu You shall also run the above command from your terminal of the project root folder, assuming your cucumber_json.py is in your root folder.